# How to loop json data in jquery or filter a certain data so that it wont repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm confuse on jquery, it's not the same on php.
[image]

I want to achieve this kind of table but the output of my jquery is this
[image]

Here is my json
[image]

Jquery:

```
$.get('/dev/api/getPODetails?id=' + id, function(data){

            $.each(data, function(index, getPODetails){

               $('.table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+getPODetails.id+'</td></tr>');
                      $('.table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+getPODetails.itemdesc+'</td></tr>');
                })
            })
    });
```

I don't know what's the problem of the loop, all I want is to display none repeating PO#. Can someone share some idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$('.table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+getPODetails.id+'</td><td>' +getPODetails.itemdesc+ '</td></tr>');` This will set 2 columns as  expected!

Comment: I'm a tad confused, because from what I can see, you are telling it to create a new row for each value? Also, this is not php? jQuery is a separate language,  don't tag it as php when the question doesn't relate to it.

Comment: oh sorry for that @Epodax,

Comment: @DhavalMarthak, Nah... the output should be the same on the example. It should be
PO#1
Itemdesc1
Itemdesc2
PO#2
Itemdesc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i make it easier way:

Controller:

```
public function getPOHeader(){

        $supplierid = Input::get('id');

        $getPOHeader = PurchaseHeader::where('partner_id', $supplierid)
                        ->get();            
        return Response::json($getPOHeader, 200, array(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    public function getPODetails(){

            $supplierid = Input::get('id');

            $getPODetails = DB::table('purchase_details')
                            ->where('purchase_details.po_no_id', $supplierid)
                            ->leftJoin('items', 'purchase_details.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
                            ->join('uoms', 'purchase_details.uom_id', '=', 'uoms.id')
                            ->select('items.description as itemdesc', 'purchase_details.qty as ordered', 'uoms.name as uom',
                                        'purchase_details.price as unitprice', 'purchase_details.disc as disc', 'purchase_details.disc_type as disc_type',
                                        'purchase_details.total_amt as netunitprice')
                                ->get();

            return Response::json($getPODetails, 200, array(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
```

My view:

```
 $.get('/dev/api/getPOHeader?id=' + id, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(index, getPOHeader){

        $.get('/dev/api/getPODetails?id=' + getPOHeader.id , function(data1){
         $('.table tbody').append('<tr><th><label ><strong>PO #'+getPOHeader.id+'</strong></label></th></tr>');
         $.each(data1, function(index, getPODetails){
            $('.table tbody').append('<tr><td><label>'+getPODetails.itemdesc+'</label></td><td><label>'+getPODetails.ordered+'</label></td><td>---------</td><td><input type="text" name="" ></td><td><label>'+getPODetails.uom+'</label></td><td><label>'+getPODetails.unitprice+'</label></td><td><label>'+getPODetails.disc+'</label></td><td><label>'+getPODetails.disc_type+'</label></td><td><label>'+getPODetails.netunitprice+'</label></td><td><label>00.00</label></td></tr>');
         })
       })    
    })
});
```

and the route:

Route::get('dev/api/getPOHeader','Search\SearchDataController@getPOHeader');
Route::get('dev/api/getPODetails','Search\SearchDataController@getPODetails');

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I think I need to separate my ID and Items JSON so that it will display the correct itemdesc in corresponds to the poid.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a separate javascript array so that no element repeats in the loop.

```
$.get('/dev/api/getPODetails?id=' + id, function(data){
    var dataDisplayed = [];

    $.each(data, function(index, getPODetails){
        if(jQuery.inArray(getPODetails.id, dataDisplayed) !== -1)
        {
            return;
        }
        $('.table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+getPODetails.id+'</td></tr>');
        $('.table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+getPODetails.itemdesc+'</td></tr>');
        dataDisplayed.push(getPODetails.id);
    })
});
```

I think the above code will work for you.. :-)

Comment: I'm curious what's the "test" for? I tried to copy and paste the code and it doesn't show any output. Removing the first if shows output but the still the same on the first picture.

Comment: I have mis-spelled the variable names... You should try it again now.. I have edited it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to store a reference to the id somewhere.

```
$.getJSON('/dev/api/getPODetails?id=' + id, function(data){
  var store = {};

  for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (!store[data[i].id]) = {itemdesc: data[i].itemdesc, ordered: 0}

    store[data[i]].ordered += parseInt(data[i].ordered);
  }

  for (var key in store) {
    $('.table tbody')
      .append('<tr><td>' + store[key].id + '</td></tr>')
      .append('<tr><td>' + store[key].itemdesc + '</td></tr>');
  }
});
```

Or something like

```
$.getJSON('/dev/api/getPODetails?id=' + id, function(data){
  var used = [];

  for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (used.indexOf(data[i].id) < 0) {
      $('.table tbody')
        .append('<tr><td>' + data[i].id + '</td></tr>')
        .append('<tr><td>' + data[i].itemdesc + '</td></tr>');

      used.push(data[i].id);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: After trying the output is still the same.

Comment: What exactly is the output?

Comment: Same result on the first picture.